# How to prove that every regular language can be obtained by some FA?

Tags: complexity-theory, regular-languages, finite-automata

I have seen this definition almost everywhere, but I don't know the underlying proof behind this definition.

Comment: You mean "*every regular language is accepted by some FA*", don't you?

Comment: Yes! I don't understand how can we prove this definition

Comment: This is covered by any textbook on automata theory. Furthermore, many people take acceptance by DFAs to be the _definition_ of regular languages. You don't prove definitions.

Comment: What now: is it a definition or theorem in your book?

Comment: How do you define regular languages?

Comment: How do you prove a definition?

Answer (score 2):

These definitions are from Wikipedia

> In theoretical computer science and formal language theory, a regular
> language is a formal language that can be expressed using a regular
> expression...
>
> ...
>
> Alternatively, a regular language can be defined as a language
> recognized by a finite automaton.

You can define a regular language as a *set of strings accepted by some  FA*. In this case **you don't have to prove anything** since a regular language **is recognized by a finite automaton by definition**.

But if you define a regular language as *a formal language that can be expressed using a regular expression* then **you can prove that it is accepted by some FA using** [Thompson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction), i.e. prove the equivalence of regular expressions and finite automata.

Comment: @rus9384 For better or worse, "finite automata" canonically refers to acceptors of regular languages, not other, extended (or restricted) models.

Comment: @rus9384 I have no idea what that is. All I'm saying is that you shouldn't say "some FA can decide non-regular languages" without explanation, since novices will take it to mean "some NFA can ..." which is wrong.